# Custom bootstrap 4 theme with angular 4 not working

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am working on a simple angular 4 application with customized bootstrap. I have customized the values of bootstrap from the website http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/. So I get bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap-theme.min.css from this website.

Now I am trying to integrate this bootstrap css with my angular 4 application.

I generated the angular application using angular cli

I tried 2 methods, but by both the ways, the custom theme css isn't applied. It still remains as default bootstrap theme which I don't want.

1. Directly import css and other files in index.html as below,

> ```
> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" 
>     integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
>
>     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
>   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"
>
>     integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4"
>
>     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
>   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css"
>
>     integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M"
>
>     crossorigin="anonymous">
>   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"
>
>     integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1"
>
>     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
>   <link href="./assets/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
> ```

the last css i.e. bootstrap-theme.min.css is my custom theme file which i downloaded from the bootstrap site.

2. Setup bootstrap using the method suggested by the website,

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-include-bootstrap

Here, I used the first method i.e. using CSS.
I made a small modification, where I added my custom theme as ,

```
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css",
  "styles.css"
],
```

Using both the above ways, the custom theme is not applied.

Can anyone suggest, how can I make the application use the custom theme file bootstrap-theme.min.css in this angular 4 application?

Comment: You use bootstrap 4 but your customized css is from bootstrap 3. Why not use SASS to customize bootstrap 4?

Comment: I have already spend much of time customizing the bootstrap, it is not possible to redo all again. Can I have some solution to use the existing custom theme file with the application? Can I downgrading to bootstrap 3 instead of 4 work?

Comment: Yes, use the bootstrap 3